# ASP.NET MVC 2 Authorize ONLY unauthenticated users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitemapprovider

im trying to figure out how to authorize only unauthenticated users. i have a sign in tab displayed in my site map and i only want it to show up when the user hasnt yet logged in.

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking doesn't quite sound like authorisation - in my opinion, an authorised user (in this case an unauthenticated user) would be served the `ActionResult` (in this case a view) whereas an unauthorised user would not. In what you describe, the `ActionResult` is returned for all users; we just want to emit additional html fr your tab to unauthenticated users.

you might just want to check `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` or `Request.IsAuthenticated` and if unauthenticated, emit the HTML for your sign in tab. You might want ot put this into an MVC UserControl

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
%>
        <!-- html here for your sign in tab -->
<%
    }
    else {
%> 
        <!-- possibly want a sign out tab here for authenticated users? -->
<%
    }
%>
```

Put the user control in the shared folder then use in a view like so

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Name of User Control"); %>
```